# How connection pooling works with different DbContext

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm interested in how connection pooling works with different DbContext.

In my application i'm using two DbContext with slightly different setup (ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly), one for read-write operations, second for readonly operations (MSSQL, server uses read-only routing).

Will EFCore use two separate connection pools in this situation, or it will use one connection pool?

Comment: Why does that matter to you? Anyway, EF is just an ADO.Net client so the normal ADO.Net connection pooling rules apply: a pool per connection configuration.

Comment: Recently my replication database died and all traffic was executed directly on primary server. Because of that primary server was overloaded with traffic and especially abnormal ammount of connections. I'm suspecting that connection ammount was high because of long queries executions with timeouts and connections from "read only" contextes.